# Ganglia gmetad failover

Tags: replication, failover, ganglia, gmetad

I want to know if it possible to have gmetad in a failover/replica scenario. My problem is the following:

I have 100 nodes that they speak to each other with multicast and they sync their gmond info. I have a separate machine that is running the gmetad (lets call it master1) that polls metrics from various gmonds (so far so good).

Now I want to be sure that if master1 dies, I will have a second gmetad (master2) that will have the same data. So I configured a second gmetad that reads the same gmonds. Now if master1 dies and comes again up after (lets say) 3 days, is there any way to get from master2 all the missed data and have a complete timeline in master1?

If there is no way to do that, can I use an NFS directory and point both the gmetads to write the rrds on the same directory?

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a multicast environment. All your rrd files will be saved at multiple places. So If you want Master1 to have the complete timeline data what you can do is back up the rrds and restart the gmond and gmetad process. Ganglia will again copy all the rrds from the multicast nodes.